# SearchView Android- with server side

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, searchview

I have node.js server connected to MongoDb, is it possible to connect it to the search option in android studio? I mean that the results of the searching(in the search view) will be shown from the db which is connected to my node.js server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear that there's no easy way to connect SearchView directly to your remote server's database.
You have to expose the data to be searched through a web service.

I'm not a NodeJs expert, but you may use [Express](http://expressjs.com/) or any other web service library for that purpose.

Let's imagine that you want to search data based on their `title` column in database. Follow these steps for server-side:

1. Define a web service entry point to allow remote clients to perform searches.

Clients may call this web service with the following URL:
`https://mynodeserver.com/data?title=some+title`.

2. Now that you have the query string, read all data from your MongoDB database whose `title` matches `searchedTitle`.
3. Return results to clients as JSON from the WebService we defined earlier.

Here is an example server-side code with ExpressJs:

```
app.get('/data', function (req, res) {
    let searchedTitle = req.query.title
    let searchResults = searchMongoDb(searchedTitle)
    res.send(searchResults)
})
```

Then, call your web service from Android whenever SearchView's content changes, passing the search query in your URL.
You may use:

- An Android HTTP client such as Volley or OkHttp
- A JSON parsing library for Java, such as GSON or Jackson.

The steps for Android client-side:

1. Define a `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`. Depending on your use case, you may write code in `onQueryTextChanged` or `onQueryTextSubmit`.
2. Call your web service using Volley/OkHttp, specifying the search query in the URL based on the template I defined earlier.
3. Parse the received JSON to a list of data.
4. Do what you want with the search results: display them as suggestions, or start a new Activity to display results in a ListView.

Hope it helps !